# Cannot generate a tooltip in HTML DOM? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tooltip

I would like to generate tooltips for my list elements using Javascript (using HTML DOM elements). What is the easiest way to do this? I am trying to generate a list of Hyperlinks, but when you mouse over each Hyperlink a tooltip pops up.

```
function print(string){
// Create a <li> element
  var node = document.createElement("LI");         

// Create an anchor element (hyperlink)
  var anchor = document.createElement("A");
  anchor.text = string;
  anchor.href = getLinkFromCert(string);


//I WANT TO GENERATE A TOOLTIP EITHER FOR MY ANCHOR ELEMENT OR FOR MY <LI> ELEMENT



// Append the anchor to <li>  
 node.appendChild(anchor);      

 // Append <li> to <ul> with id="myList"
 document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);    

}
```

Below is the resulting HTML generated with my js. The  elements are the actual tooltips for the anchor elemements. But they are not showing up.
[image]

Here is the tooltip library I am trying to use:
https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#tooltips-section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the default tooltips readable by screen readers,

```
anchor.title="This will popup";
```

or

```
node.title="This will be an LI tooltip"
```

Example. Mouse over the bullet and mouse over the link

```js
function getLinkFromCert() {}
function print(string) {
  // Create a <li> element
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  node.title="LI title:"+string;
  
  // Create an anchor element (hyperlink)
  var anchor = document.createElement("A");
  anchor.text = string;
  anchor.href = getLinkFromCert(string);
  anchor.title="Anchor title:"+string;

  // Append the anchor to <li>  
  node.appendChild(anchor);

  // Append <li> to <ul> with id="myList"
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
}

window.onload = function() {
  print("tooltip");
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

Comment: Or some JS tooltip script

Comment: The I would like to use this script (MDL) to generate tooltips:https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#tooltips-section.  I can do that without JQuery right? The problem is I dont know how to generate the "for" attribute using Javascript HTML DOM.

Comment: tag.setAttribute("for","someID")

Comment: Hey, for some reason I my MDL tooltips still aren't working. I posted a screenshot. Can you take a look?

Comment: Do you activate the tooltip after adding the html?

Comment: I have no idea. Can you make a jsfiddle.net or a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a script instead of writing tooltips yourself. I recommend tipsy, which you find [here](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/).

If you are using Boostrap, then there are also tooltips already integrated. You find the description [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

Comment: I don't know jQuery. I'm just using plain JS right now.

Comment: jQuery will make things alot easier for you :)